# Spellcheck in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, spell-check

In MacOS X it is possible to have spellcheck OS wide for all applications where you have an input. Is something similar possible with Ubuntu? So that I have spellcheck for e.g. skype?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is anything approaching this functionality yet available on Ubuntu. It's been proposed time and again on ubuntu brainstorm, and these suggestions have been collected under this idea: [**Idea #364: More comprehensive dictionary program**](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/364/). (Check the duplicates assigned to this idea).

Check [this post](http://simulacra.in/2007/11/random-ubuntu-tip-of-the-day-spell-check-everywhere/) to see a rigged up implementation with the same goal in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I am unable to just add a comment and this'll go in here as a new post to the thread. :-(

I tried to use nagul's link, to see Idea #364, but that site brainstorm.ubuntu.com is apparently shut-down. I found this answer, regarding the issue:

[Ubuntu Brainstorm site down/dead](https://askubuntu.com/questions/321289/ubuntu-brainstorm-site-down-dead)?

P.S. 
So far, I've gotten to [here](http://eion.robbmob.com/) and I'm not sure whether there is something *better* && so, still looking.