# ubuntu general spellcheker

Tags: linux, ubuntu, spell-check

I am wondering if there is a ubuntu application that can spell check any text in any application running.

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/47441/spellcheck-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is almost a duplicate of this one:[**Spellcheck in Ubuntu**](https://superuser.com/questions/47441/spellcheck-in-ubuntu). My [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/47441/spellcheck-in-ubuntu/47467#47467) links to a post that has a workable (if not convenient) implementation to do a system-wide spell-check.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that there's a built in spell checker in the form of Aspell, if it's not working everywhere, it may be because some applications don't register their textboxes in a way it can see them.